# Remark that an element is in a set in equation environment

Tags: equations, symbols

i'd like to remark that an element is in a set when typing an implication in equation environment.

To be more clear I'll give an example:

> let's say that $F\subset K$ are fields and that $(\alpha+t\beta),(\alpha+s\beta)\in K$, where $t,s\in F$; it follows that $(t-s)\beta\in K$, so $\beta \in K$ because $(t-s)\in K$; so we also have $\alpha\in K$.

That is my attempt:

```
\begin{equation*}
    (\alpha+t\beta)-(\alpha+s\beta)=(t-s)\beta\in\K_s
    \implies \beta\in\K_s
    \implies \alpha\in\K_s,
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

I would like to make more clear why implications holds true by remarking wich element is in which field.

When I handwrite something like that I just put a rotated $\in$ symbol below the given element, and then the set below.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Maybe writing it in text as you did here?

Comment: Write in plain language and avoid blackboard or handwritten note abbreviations. Piling up symbols doesn't add to clarity; actually they make for obscurity. Anyway, this is off-topic here.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll just write it